# Running parallell tests on OSX

Tags: macos, testing, safari, virtual-machine

I'm trying to run parallel tests in the Safari browser on OSX. The host machine is OSX but I'm unsure what the best approach is to virtualise OSX in order to run 2 or 3 parallels test. I've been looking at QEMU but most approaches seem to be for Windows. Is QEMU a good approach for a host OSX to virtualise a OSX for web browser testing?

Comment: This is all VERY subjective.  You can also take a look at Apple's official docs. 
 https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/testing_with_webdriver_in_safari

Comment: @jnovack Ive looked at the official documents but don't the usage of web driver on the host machine prevent regular usage when test are running?